# nodejs express how to send response back to browser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to make a sign-in application in nodejs,using angularjs and express. From angularjs I am sending $http post request to server , where first it should check if the data is already present in MongoDB and send response back to client.

The Problem is, I am not able to configure the response with header information. Every time i am getting

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

or

> MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

```
Here is my app.js code.

app.post('/signin',function (req,res) {
    console.log('i recievied a get request in app.js = /signin');   
    console.log(req.body);
    db.users.findOne({$or: [{username: req.body.username}, {email: req.body.email}]},function (err, data){
    if ( err ) throw err;
    if (err) { res.send(err); return; }
    //res.json({ data: "Invalid Password" });
    if ( err ) {console.log('user found already in db'); console.log(err)};
    //res.json(data);
    //console.log('user found already in db')
    //res.redirect('/foo/bar');
    res.end('user found already in db');
    //res.send({ data: 'user found already in db' })
    //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    //res.json({ a: 1 });   
    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    //res.send("jai shree ram");
    //res.end();
    //return;
    });

    db['users'].insert({
        username : req.body.username,
        firstname : req.body.firstname,
        lastname : req.body.lastname,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password,
        createdAt : new Date(),
        role : "user",
        approvedBy : req.body.approver.username,
        status : "locked"
    },function (err, data){
    if ( err ) throw err;   
    //if ( err ) {console.log('user created in db'); console.log(err)}; 
    //res.json(data);
    //if (err) { res.send(err); return; }
    //res.json({ data: "Password" });
    res.end('user created in db');
    //res.send({ data: 'user created in db' })
    //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    //res.json({ a: 1 });
    //res.end();
    //return;
    })

});
```

And from browser i am placing below request

```
$http({
            url: '/signin',
            method: "POST",
            data: $scope.SignInForm
            //headers: {'Content-Type': 'myapplication/json','charset' : 'utf-8'}
            })
            .then(function (res){
                console.log(res.data)                       
                },function (error){
                console.log(error)
            });
```

I tried out many things but not able to succeed.

Comment: what do you get on browser? does the server throw any error?

Comment: No @Theo, i am not getting error in browser. I will be handling the response message in pop up in browser based on response.

Comment: can you print what the response code & body on the network tool of chrome? and the server logs as well? that's the only way we can help you mate

Comment: why you took many error responses, just send   `res.end(err);`

Comment: @sand do you getting any error?

Comment: I am just trying many things. I just want to handle the message properly in browser whether "user created" or "user already present".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of setting headers and sending data is wrong . First set headers and then send the response to front end.

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send({ data: 'user created in db' })
```

Secondly your insert and find are running in parallel. Insert should only work if user is not found in db

```
app.post('/signin',function (req,res) {
    console.log('i recievied a get request in app.js = /signin');   
    console.log(req.body);
    db.users.findOne({$or: [{username: req.body.username}, {email: req.body.email}]},function (err, data){
        if (err) { 
            //Error Case (send to front end)
            res.send( error) 
        } else {
            if(data == null) {//Condition to check whether data exists or not
                db['users'].insert({
                    username : req.body.username,
                    firstname : req.body.firstname,
                    lastname : req.body.lastname,
                    email : req.body.email,
                    password : req.body.password,
                    createdAt : new Date(),
                    role : "user",
                    approvedBy : req.body.approver.username,
                    status : "locked"
                },function (err, data){
                    if ( err ) throw err;   
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    res.send({ data: 'user created in db' })
                });
            } else {
                 res.send(data)
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Yamini. I got the message in browser but at server side the application crashed with message "MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myapp.users index: email_1 dup key"

Comment: find and insert both are async processes so as per your snippet the callback of one process will not wait for other one's callback .

Comment: Can you please explain me exact use case of yours so I can help. It seems to me that your find function returns "User already found in db" and still your insert function tries to insert the user as they are executing in parallel

Comment: Thanks @Yamini. But this solution is giving error , "MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myapp.users index: email_1 dup key:"

Comment: @sand can you please tell what is the response of findOne if the user is found it seems to me it is not coming in if(err) block  . If I am right then we will have to check in else block like  if(err) {  send error to front end} else { if(user found condition ) send message to front end else do insert operation }

Comment: @sand I have updated my answer for latest use case . I hope it helps now . There will be some status code to check if user exists which will help us to find whether to insert or not

Comment: thanks @Yamini. This worked. I just put "if(data == null)"  for "some condition to check if user exists" and interchanged the if-else code.

Comment: @sand great :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Because `node js` works `asynchrounously` your `insert` wont wait for `findOne` to complete so, you are getting `duplicate error`

You need to `insert` data in the **callback function** of `findOne`

```
app.post('/signin', function (req, res) {
    console.log('i recievied a get request in app.js = /signin');
    console.log(req.body);
    db.users.findOne({ $or: [{ username: req.body.username }, { email: req.body.email }] }, function (err, data) {
        if (data) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.end({ data: 'user found already in db' })
        }
        else {
            db['users'].insert({
                username: req.body.username,
                firstname: req.body.firstname,
                lastname: req.body.lastname,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                role: "user",
                approvedBy: req.body.approver.username,
                status: "locked"
            }, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    res.end({ data: err })
                }
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.send({ data: 'user created in db' })

            })
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Sravan. But this solution is giving error , "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined" and "TypeError: cb is not a function" error.

Comment: where did you take `sort`

Comment: Sorry @Sravan, i am getting "MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myapp.users index: email_1 dup key:" message. and application crashing.

Comment: also please console.log(data) in `findOne` response

Comment: This solution is giving error, "process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer". This is for line "res.end({ data: 'user found already in db' })"